# Page reload goes back to index.php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using this script within my website:

```
<script>
//refresh the page once to load slideshow correctly
setTimeout(function(){
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload()}}, 1000);
</script>
```

When it is executed the current URL (`http://.../slider/Cycle2/cycle2-tile.php?selection=3%2C4)`) is not realoaded and appended with '#' but the index.php (`(http://.../#loaded)`) is loaded instead. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to happen instead? By the code above, it seems to do its job fine.

Comment: I would like to reload the current URL (containing the script) as indicated in the text after the code. Instead index.php is loaded and appended with '#'

Comment: Is slider/Cycle2/cycle2-tile.php included in index.php, like a frame, iframe etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<script>
//refresh the page once to load slideshow correctly
var currentLocation=window.location.href;
setTimeout(function(){
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = currentLocation + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload()}}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I don't really get why the other solution(s) didn't work though. Is it just me, or is the documentation really imprecise concerning the window, location, href objects? Can anyone provider an explanation?

Comment: @Pete It may relate to this keyword

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:
    `window.location.href = window.location.href + '#loaded';`
instead of
    `window.location = window.location + '#loaded';`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried that, even set .href after all location object. Still loads the index.php and appends the '#' there :(

Comment: I don't remember using window.location.reload to redirect a page.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. location.href = is enough to activate the redirect.

Comment: Ok, erased the window object from all four expressions, now it stays in the same window, but the '#' is still not appended to the current URL

Comment: My code snipet:
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.href = window.location.href + "#coucou";
 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>